# View list file in folder External Storage

Tags: android, kotlin

La verdad no entiendo porque no me lista las imágenes de la carpeta photos dentro del External Storage. Tengo el código similar en otra APP y funciona perfecto. Seguramente me estoy olvidando de algo.

```
val path =
            File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "gesis/photos")

        if (!path.exists())
        {
            if (!path.mkdirs())
            {
                Log.e("TareaCampo", "Error al crear la carpeta")
            }
        }

        /**
         * /storage/emulated/0/Documents/gesis/photos
          */
        val files = path.listFiles()
        if (files != null && files.isNotEmpty()){
            for (file in files){
                Log.e("TareaCampo", "Nombre de Archivo: ${file.name}")
            }

        }
```

La variable path tiene el contenido que puse en los comentarios:

```
 /storage/emulated/0/Documents/gesis/photos
```

Y en la imagen que anexo se ve que en `Dispositivo/Documents/gesis/photos` existen 3 imágenes

No entiendo porque "files" me dá nulo, como si no encontrara nada.

En `AndroidManifest.xml` tengo

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

GRACIAS !!![image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7rzf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente te comento que además de definir el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` es importante realizar la petición manual del permiso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

recuerda también que no es necesario usar:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Ya que es inherente a el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

---

El problema se debe a que estas buscando en un directorio diferente a:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Documents/gesis/photos
```

En tu explorador de archivos debes ver esta ruta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

te comento que esta es otra forma de obtener el listado de archivos en la ruta:

```
val path = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "gesis/photos")

File(path.toString()).walkTopDown().forEach {                
    Log.i("TareaCampo", "tec: " + it)
}
```

Comment: Gracias Jorgesys por tu comentario

Comment: @desarrollosTELLO el problema es principalmente que la ruta debe ser la que se encuentra en storage/emulated/0/Documents/gesis